# Android list Background

Tags: android, list

```
public class Speaking extends ListActivity {
    String clas[] = { "meeting", "Farewells" ,"Health", "Normal Life", "Date", "About", "Formal"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Full screen kodu
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Speaking.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, clas));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        String c = clas[position];
        try {

            Class ourClass = Class.forName("com.english.english." + c);
            Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Speaking.this, ourClass);
            startActivity(ourIntent);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

How can I change background color of List as white ?

Comment: in this class i don't have xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Get the list by getListView() method.
2. Apply the calor using setBackgroundColor(Color) or by the layout xml.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add this line into your onCreate method:

```
setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_xml_file);
```

Second in that layout resource file set the background color of your ListView element:

```
android:background="@color/my_listview_background_color"
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your own selector drawabel for the list items. Create an xml drawable file `list_row_bg.xml` with :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/red" />
   <item android:drawable="@color/white" />
</selector>
```

Then then in yout onCreate :

```
ListView listView = getListView();
Resources res = getResources();
Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromXml(res, res.getXml(R.drawable.list_row_bg.xml));
listView.setSelector(drawable);
```

Answer (score 0):

For `ListView` use `background` attribute

```
android:background="#FFFFFF"
```

through programmatically

```
listview.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
```